# Google map is not centered correctly while presenting viewController

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, storyboard

i was just adding GMSMapView to a view inside viewcontroller but it is not centered as in `CLLocation` is giving right coordinates, the blue dot is coming on the right spot but just the map is slightly shifted to down right i don't know why. I tried running it directly as in the first page to open after the launch of app then it works fine but when i present my VC the map gets shifted. Please can anyone help.

This happens only when i present viewcontroller not when i push viewcontroller

As you can see the the correct location is where the blue dot is coming:

[image]

Comment: We need to see some code.

Comment: So your issue the blue dot is not focusing to the centre right ?

Comment: You need to set camera position to focus correctly

Comment: I have the same bug. And it happens only on some iphones, like 7, 8, 8plus. Haven't tested all but I am sure it doesnt happen on iphone X.

Comment: @Kokolo / anyone found any solution? I'm also getting same error

Comment: I have the same issue, anyone found the solution?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. What worked for me was moving the code to center from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear`

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: LocationConstants.defaultLat, longitude: LocationConstants.defaultLong, zoom: 15.0)
}
```

Interestingly enough the same code works in another `UIViewController` in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.8683,
                                          longitude: 151.2086,
                                          zoom: 16)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.bounds, camera: camera)

let mapView = GMSMapView(frame: self.view.bounds)